# Scaling up grep find and copy to large folder (xargs?)

Tags: bash, grep, xargs, cp

I would like to search a directory for any file that matches any of a list of words.  If a file matches, I would like to copy that file into a new directory.  I created a small batch of test files and got the following code working:

```
cp `grep -lir 'word\|word2\|word3\|word4\|word5' '/Users/originallocation'` '/Users/newlocation'
```

Unfortunately, when I run this code on a large folder with a few thousand files it says the argument list is too long for `cp`.  I think I need to loop this or use a `xargs` but I can't figure out how to make the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal change from what you have would be:

```
grep -lir 'word\|word2\|word3\|word4\|word5' '/Users/originallocation' | \
  xargs cp -t '/Users/newlocation'
```

But, don't use that.  Because you never know when you will encounter a filename with spaces or newlines in it, null-terminated strings should be used.  On linux/GNU, add the -Z option to grep and -0 to xargs:

```
grep -Zlir 'word\|word2\|word3\|word4\|word5' '/Users/originallocation' | \
  xargs -0 cp -t '/Users/newlocation'
```

On Macs (and AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, *BSD), the grep options change slightly but, more importantly, the GNU `cp -t` option is not available.  A workaround is:

```
grep -lir --null 'word\|word2\|word3\|word4\|word5' '/Users/originallocation' | \
  xargs -0 -I fname cp fname '/Users/newlocation'
```

This is less efficient because a new instance of `cp` has to be run for each file to be copied.

Comment: +1: Note that the `-t target` option to GNU `cp` is very useful, but not universally available with other variants of `cp`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Yes, I just added a workaround.  Are there any important platforms besides Macs which lack `-t`?

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'important'.  AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, *BSD are all affected; basically, it is only platforms that use GNU core utils (or thereabouts) that have it, and AFAIK that means Linux does and everything else Unix-like does not.  I've not got access to AIX, HP-UX, Solaris any more (for the last 9 months or so), but they've probably not changed since then.

Comment: @John1024: Great answer, but (a) the equivalent of GNU's `-Z` option on OSX is `--null` and (b) I wish you made the `-Z`/`-0` combo the first and _recommended_ solution: there's really no good reason NOT to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution for those without `grep -r`. Using `find + egrep + xargs` , hope there is no file with same file name in different folders. Secondly, I replaced the ugly style of  `word\|word2\|word3\|word4\|word5`

```
find . -type f -exec egrep -l 'word|word2|word3|word4|word5' {} \; |xargs -i cp {}  /LARGE_FOLDER
```

Comment: Your quotes are mismatched. Also, if `egrep -lr` and `xargs` can do the job, as in @John1024's answer, what's the advantage of adding `find` to the mix?

Comment: My system (solaris) doesn't support `grep -r`,  this command with find will be common。Secondly I didn't like the style of `"word\|word2\|word3\|word4\|word5'`, personal habit.

Comment: Got it. Perhaps you should preface your post with that, along the lines of "alternative solution for those without `grep -r`". By mismatched quotes I meant that your string literal is broken: it starts with `"` and ends with `\``.